# In wordpress User group using php

Tags: php, wordpress

How to display (echo) the user group using php.

I have displayed user name, and user email and user ID.

But I would like to add the user group also.

How to do that?

Now I have created a php code to list name, id and email address.

```
<?php
    $order = 'user_nicename';
    $users = get_users( 'search=*' ); 
    foreach($users as $user) :
    echo $user->user_nicename ; ?>
    echo $user->user_firstname; ?>
    echo $user->user_lastname; ?>
    echo $user->user_email; ?>
    endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: You mean by user role ?

Comment: No I just want to get the user group and also user role if it is possible.

Comment: What you mean by user group ?

Comment: Hmm Yes :) I just want to display the user group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, where `$user_id` is the id of the user you want to display the role(*group*)

```
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );
$user_roles = $user->roles;

foreach($user_roles as $role) {
  echo $role;
}
```

UPDATED to be applicable for [UAM WordPress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-access-manager/):

Try this

```
global $userAccessManager;

if (isset($userAccessManager)) {
    $userId = <insert-user-id-here>;
    $uamAccessHandler = $userAccessManager->getAccessHandler();
    $userGroupsForUser = $uamAccessHandler->getUserGroupsForObject('user', $userId);

    print_r($userGroupsForUser);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much @Plamen Nikolov. Now I get the user role. But It would be nice, If I also get the user group I allocated to every user by UAM (User Access Manager) plugin.

Comment: Just updated the answer to include code for the UAM plugin usage

Answer (score 1):

Check the wordpress user meta table to find the key to fetch the user group's key which the plugin have used.

Then use the get_user_meta() in your code with that key. It works

Answer (score 1):

The plugin UAM User Access Manager has slighlty changed some functions. Therefore the [answer by Plamen Nikolov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22958197/7964143) should be edited like this in order to work:

```
global $userAccessManager;

if (isset($userAccessManager)) {
    $userId = <insert-user-id-here>;
    $uamAccessHandler = $userAccessManager->getAccessHandler();
    $userGroupsForUser = $uamAccessHandler->getUserGroupsForObject('_user_', $userId);

    print_r($userGroupsForUser);
}
```