# wordpress show media files for user

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to present the user only his media files but only if he is in a custom group (Teachers). If he is Author or above he can see all media files.

e.g. I have a user Teacher 1 and he is in group Author and Teachers.
User Accountant is in group Author.

Teacher can see only his files, Accountant can see all files.

I tried the following funcition

```
 function wpb_show_current_user_attachments( $query ) {
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
if ( $user_id && !current_user_can('activate_plugins') && !current_user_can('edit_others_posts') ) {
/*        $query['author'] = $user_id;*/
    $query['Teacher'] = $user_id;
}
return $query;
} 

add_filter( 'ajax_query_attachments_args', 'wpb_show_current_user_attachments' );
```

Thank you

Comment: I doubt that `$query['Teacher'] = $user_id;` makes sense. Just because you have a group called `Teacher`, will not mean that the WP query mechanism will support that as a filterable property. Much more likely, this should simply be the part you commented out here, `$query['author'] = $user_id;` - you want to filter the media items by the _author_ that uploaded them. (That is “post author” as in WP terms, no relation to any group names.) You just need to decide whether to add that filter or not, based on whether your current user is a teacher or not.

Comment: aaa... ok I see the difference now, but still...  how can i achieve that?

Comment: What exactly? Figuring out whether the current user is a Teacher or not? That depends on how exactly you implemented “groups”; probably by checking the user’s roles? https://stackoverflow.com/a/22958197/10955263